# Saving state of treeview menu in browser storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, treeview

I've got an html page that is built up using javascript. Now I want the page to "remember" which treeview has been opened. When the menu is closed the class 'testclosed' is added to the div.

Scenario: The user opens the menu and then clicks on a button to complete his task. After this the user must come back to this page and check if everything is filled properly. THe user then has to find his item again. Therefore, I want the browser to remember which item was open when he left the page

I have found part of the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280585/saving-state-of-menu-after-page-reload) question already asked here.The only thing that I cannot seem to find is how to do the check so that I can save it in the browser storage

EDIT: Here is the code that toggles the menu(open and closed)

```
$('.testlevel2').click(function () {
    var group = $(this).attr('group');
    var groupval = $(this).attr('groupvalue');
    $("div").find("[" + group + "='" + groupval + "']").toggleClass("testclosed");
});
 return "</div>";
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: maybe local storage can help you: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Can you show some of your markup? The localstorage api will do this but it's hard to write an example without seeing your code.

Comment: I don't see how my code is relevant. The question is how to check for the class (as added in the last edit).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to make a relevant example without seeing your code. You can use the `localStorage` api to store the class name of the opened menu, then check it once you load the page:

```
// Call this when you open and close a menu
function saveSettings(openMenuClassName) {
    // Store value in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('openMenu', openMenuClassName)
}

function loadSettings () {
   // Get value from localStorage
   var openMenu = localStorage.getItem('openMenu');
   if (openMenu) $(openMenu).show();
}

// Check for the saved setting on page ready
$(document).ready(loadSettings);
```

Read more about `localStorage` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 0):

Sinan had the right idea and set me on the right track. This is the answer I eventually came up with.

The "testclosed" class is added when the item is closed. This was already the case as in the question.

What I've done in the save() function below is set the localStorage to true if the class is found.

In the load() function I then get the localStorage item and if it is set to true, the class "testclosed" is removed.

```
$(document).ready(load);



function save() {
   var saveDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("testclosed"); 
   if (saveDiv) {

      localStorage.setItem("isMenuOpen", true);

   }

}

function load() {
   var isMenuOpen = localStorage.getItem("isMenuOpen");
   if (isMenuOpen) {

      $(".testitem").removeClass("testclosed");

   }

}
```