# Saving State of jQuery Collpasing Navigation Menu

Tags: jquery, treeview, local-storage

I'm looking to save the state of my treeview menu. I've bee following answers on here, in particular this one:

[Save State of Treeview Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482998/saving-state-of-treeview-menu-in-browser-storage)

I have successfully got saving to localStorage working however cannot get my page to load based on that saved data.

My broad understanding of the method is:

- Append unique CSS class to uniquely identify element containing the open menu (in my case '`#has-sub active'`)
- Save the css class to Local Storage
- On page load retrieve the Local Storage variable to open the same element

I don't though understand how the load concept can work. In my menu javascript code I am only adding the `#has-sub active` class when the menu element is clicked.

On page load my local storage has a variable `openMenu` with a value of `'#has-sub active'` which I want to apply to the same element that was clicked on the previous page. However I don't know what mechanism or element property I can use to identify the same element because on page load the classes added by my Javascript are removed, and I can't hard code an 'openMenu' style class to my HTML has obviously the active menu item will change.

My code below, I have for now only been trying to get it working with the first child menu items, not second.

I'm also not sure if I've put `$(document).ready(loadSettings);` in the correct place in the script.

**EDIT:** Added jsfiddle here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ks3hfbuc/1/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Call this when you open and close a menu
    function saveSettings(openMenuClassName) {
        // Store value in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('openMenu', openMenuClassName)
    }

    function loadSettings () {
       // Get value from localStorage
       var openMenu = localStorage.getItem('openMenu');
       if (openMenu) $(openMenu).slideDown('normal');
    }

    // Check for the saved setting on page ready
    $(document).ready(loadSettings);

    //Check if first child has sub-menu
    $('#cssmenu > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");

    //Behaviour
    $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {

        //Each time an element is click load the next DOM element into variable
        var checkElement = $(this).next();

        //Remove 'Active' from all classes and add to element clicked 
        $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

        //Check if element is UL AND if element is visible
        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {

            //TRUE - has sub-menu and is visible therefore collapse and remove active
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            checkElement.slideUp('normal');
        }

        //Check if element is UL AND if element is not visible
        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {

            //TRUE - has sub-menu and is not visible therefore collapse open sub-menu and
            //$('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            saveSettings('#has-sub active');
        }

        if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;    
        }
    });

    //Check if second child has sub-menu
    $('#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");

    //Behaviour
    $('#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li > a').click(function() {

        //Each time an element is click load the next DOM element into variable
        var checkElement = $(this).next();

        //Remove 'Active' from all classes and add to element clicked 
        $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

        //Check if element is UL AND if element is visible
        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {

            //TRUE - has sub-menu and is visible therefore collapse and remove active
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            checkElement.slideUp('normal');
        }

        //Check if element is UL AND if element is not visible
        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {

            //TRUE - has sub-menu and is not visible therefore collapse open sub-menu and
            //$('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        }

        if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;    
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: working jsfiddle or codepen example would be easy to provide a solution.

Comment: I've not done that before, let me look into it - thanks.

Comment: @MrKhan jsfiddle here - not sure I've done it right... https://jsfiddle.net/ks3hfbuc/1/

Comment: yes you did alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so firstly you were suppose to add the active class to the element when fetching  menu. In the html give each a tag an id which will be used to get reference of that particular element.

```
var menu = $("#"+activeMenu); //========> get the selected menu
menu.closest('li').addClass('active'); //=============> Add active class to to.
```

Then you had to call the child UL of the selected Menu and simply apply slideDown on it like this.

```
var ul =  menu.next(); //==============> Get the child UL of the selected menu
if (menu) ul.slideDown('normal'); //======> slidedown the child UL of the selected
```

The complete code:

Html:

```
<div id="cssmenu">

  <ul>

    <li>
      <a id="news" href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/news/">News</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/studio-news/">Studio</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/independent-and-cult/">Independent &amp; Cult</a>    </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/world-cinema/">World Cinema</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a id="discussion" href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/discussion/">Discussion</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/history/">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/theory-and-debate/">Theory &amp; Debate</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/reviews/">Reviews</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a id="business" href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/business/">Business</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/funding/">Funding</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/box-office/">Box Office</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/marketing/">Marketing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a id="filmmaking"  href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/filmmaking/">Filmmaking</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/development/">Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/pre-production/">Pre-Production</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/production/">Production</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/cinematography/">Cinematography</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/lighting/">Lighting</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/grip/">Grip</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/post-production/">Post-Production</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/vfx/">VFX</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/editing/">Editing</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/colour-grading/">Colour Grading</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/sound/">Sound</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/titles/">Titles</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://www.myexamplewebsite99.com/kernal_category/distribution/">Distribution</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // Call this when you open and close a menu
  function saveSettings(openMenuClassName) {
    // Store value in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('activeMenu', openMenuClassName)
  }

  function loadSettings() {
    // Get value from localStorage
    var activeMenu = localStorage.getItem('activeMenu');
    var menu = $("#"+activeMenu); //========> get the selected menu
        var ul =  menu.next(); //==============> Get the child UL of the selected menu
    menu.closest('li').addClass('active'); //=============> Add active class to to. Sub-headingclass is already added to all elenents in the beignning.

    if (menu) ul.slideDown('normal'); //======> slidedown the child UL of the selected Element
  }

  // Check for the saved setting on page ready
  $(document).ready(loadSettings);

  //Check if first child has sub-menu
  $('#cssmenu > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");

  //Behaviour
  $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
    alert('here1')
    //Each time an element is click load the next DOM element into variable
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    let currentElement = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(checkElement);

    //Remove 'Active' from all classes and add to element clicked 
    //$('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

    //Check if element is UL AND if element is visible
    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {

      //TRUE - has sub-menu and is visible therefore collapse and remove active
      //$(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
      checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }

    //Check if element is UL AND if element is not visible
    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {

      //TRUE - has sub-menu and is not visible therefore collapse open sub-menu and
      //$('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
      checkElement.slideDown('normal');
      saveSettings(currentElement);
    }

    if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });

  //Check if second child has sub-menu
  $('#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");

  //Behaviour
  $('#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li > a').click(function() {
    //Each time an element is click load the next DOM element into variable
    var checkElement = $(this).next();

    //Remove 'Active' from all classes and add to element clicked 
    $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

    //Check if element is UL AND if element is visible
    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {

      //TRUE - has sub-menu and is visible therefore collapse and remove active
      $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
      checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }

    //Check if element is UL AND if element is not visible
    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {

      //TRUE - has sub-menu and is not visible therefore collapse open sub-menu and
      //$('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
      checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }

    if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks.I can see your logic however I'm running into a problem with the ```checkElement``` variable being stored with the ```saveSettings``` function. When I debug it says that the value being stored is ```undefined```. This is my first time using JS console logs to debug so I'm finding it harder to work out why, the console is logging  this ```a.fn.init [ul, selector: "", prevObject: a.fn.init(1), context: a]```

Comment: check now its updated. It was showing undefined because i had not updated the html ids. You have to provide ids for each a tag to get their reference.

Comment: Thanks, I've update the function that outputs the HTML to add those and it is now working. It's not smooth but it is functional! Each time the page loads it is trigger the menu to slide down based on ```if (menu) ul.slideDown('normal');```, is there a way to load the page already open?

Comment: you can use the same strategy and apply it on onload event